# Flex 3 combobox: filter XMLListCollection datasource

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, filter, xmllist

(I'm using Cairngorm)
I have a combobox that displays items form an XMLListCollection that's in my model.
I want to only view the items (XML) whose "sent" properties is false.. like item.sent == 'false'.
This filter must apply only to this specific combobox, not everything that's bound to the XMLListCollection source.
And of course it must update and refresh the filter if the source changes..

How can I do it? I'm trying to use filterFunction but don't understand how it works...
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to copy all the data, as Christophe says. You can create another `ListCollectionView` which is actually a view of some list and apply filter to it. 
So if `xmlListCollection` is your collection, you can try the following code:

```
var listView:ListCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(xmlListCollection.list);
listView.filterFunction =  someFunction;
listView.refresh();
```

`listView` should be always in sync with your collection, unless you swap underlying `xmlListCollection` source or list.

Comment: That actually made my day. I can't believe I didn't know that since I've been working around this for a couple of times in recent projects. +1